# JasperReports - wrong cut stretch field

Tags: jasper-reports, stretch

I have a problem with stretch field in *JasperReports 5.2.0* (designed by *iReport 5.1.0*). When rows print on new page, last row on before page is wrong cut.

Columns (AÚ - Zústatek) are from subreport. Field (112 on image) have these properties:

```
Position Type:               Fix Relative to Top
Stretch Type:                Relative to Tallest Object
Print When Detail Overflows: True
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the wrong cut of the field, need set the "Split Type = Prevent" in Band Properties of the 'Detail' band of the report. Therefore, if the field with multiple lines were cut in the last line of the page, this last line will be printed on the next page.